# Getting value of multiple <span> tags in HTML/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I'm hoping someone can help me out with this...I followed the tutorial here: http://jsbin.com/hehurot/5/edit?html,css,js,console,output to create a field on an HTML form which contains tags. Now when I click submit on my form I want to grab the data in that field with tags and do something with it (save to database).

How would I go about grabbing the data from the field since each tag is a ?

Here is my current code for the tag field:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Equipment</label>
    <div id="tags" class="col-sm-9">
       <span>Hardhat</span>
       <span>Steel Toe Boots</span>
       <input id="equipment" type="text" name="equipment" value="" placeholder="Add equipment" >
    </div>
</div>
```

The JS to make the tag field work (the CSS is available on the link above)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){ 
        $("#tags input").on({
          focusout : function() {
            var txt= this.value.replace(/[^a-z0-9\+\-\.\#]/ig,'');
            if(txt) $("<span/>",{text:txt.toLowerCase(), insertBefore:this});
            this.value="";
          },
          keyup : function(ev) {
            if(/(188|13)/.test(ev.which)) $(this).focusout(); 
          }
        });
        $('#tags').on('click', 'span', function() {
          /*if(confirm("Remove "+ $(this).text() +"?")) */$(this).remove(); 
        });
      });
</script>
```

Now in my JS file, how can I get the values saved as separate 's?

I tried the following but this does not work, returns empty string:

```
'equipment': $('#tags').val()
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: I would give your `span` elements a class name. You could then use jquery to get all the `span` tags by doing `$('.mySpans')` and then looping through the array of tags and building them how you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var tags = $('#tags span').map(function () {
  return $(this).text();
});
```

Follow-up:

> I modified it a bit to save all the values from the  to a comma separated list.

```
var tags = $('#tags span').map(function () {
  return $(this).text();
});

tags = Array.prototype.join.call(tags, ",");
console.log(tags);
```

> Followup question, in Javascript how can I add a  tag
>   programatically? I want to loop through the comma separated list and
>   add each value back to  tags.

```
$('#tags').append(tags.split(",").map(function (tag) {
  return "<span>" + tag + "</span>";
}));
```

Comment: Thanks! That works, I modified it a bit to save all the values from the <span> to a comma separated list. Followup question, in Javascript how can I add a <span> tag programatically? I want to loop through the comma separated list and add each value back to <span> tags.

Comment: I've updated my solution with a method to add tags to the element.

Comment: Thanks Dylon. I will try this when I get home. I have this tag field on a form in my app, would there be any problems with populating the <span> tags when the form is opened?

Comment: No, there shouldn't be any problems with that.

Comment: Hmm, I just tried this, when I open my form, and the code runs to add the <span> tags, they dont actually get added. I tried putting in some alerts and the values that are split are there, but it does not look like the form is updated with the <span>s. Is there a way for me to refresh it or something I should check?

Comment: Ah! I figured it out, I had two fields named tags, each was on a different form. When it was trying to populate with the <span>s it was trying to populate on the form that wasn't open! Thanks for all the help, I will mark your answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery's `.each()` http://api.jquery.com/each/:

```
a = []; $('#tags > span').each(function(){a.push(this.innerHTML)});

// a => ["php", "c++", "jquery"]
```

---

> how can I add a `<span>` tag programmatically? I want to loop through
>   the comma separated list and add each value back to `<span>` tags.

Using `jQuery.each()` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/:

```
$.each(["php", "c++", "jquery"], function(i,v){
  $('#tags').prepend($(document.createElement('span')).text(v))
});
```

Comment: The code to split the <span>s into an array works, but when I use the prepend function to add the <span>s back nothing happens. They are not added to my html. Note that this tags field is on a form in html. @soawesomeman

Comment: @user2573690 It should work with your original code. See here I've added tags for `[1,2,3]`: http://jsbin.com/jugaloqufu/edit?html,css,js,console,output